# Meteor.js: Remove and insert simultaneously

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a simple collection that renders like so

```
{{#each posts}}
    {{> post}}
{{/each}}
```

While `posts` is defined to give me the three latest posts

```
return Posts.find({}, {sort: {timestamp: -1}, limit: 3})
```

When I insert a new post, the client renders it immediately (displaying a total of 4 posts) and a few ms later the oldest post is removed from DOM. This returns me to viewing the three latest posts.

My problem here is the brief period of time in which 4 posts are displayed. Is there any way to let the client know that it should remove the oldest post at the same time as it renders the newest post?

Comment: How are you performing the remove?

Comment: I'm not actually removing anything. The client renders the three latest posts and as a new one is inserted, the oldest post is now the fourth latest and should not be displayed anymore. There is a gap in time between when the new post appears and when the old post disappears.

Comment: this is because of latency compensation https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/latency-compensation/ . You can implement your own observeChanges http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/observe_changes

Comment: also most probably you dont use a meteor server method for insert

Comment: I'm quite sure this is not because of latency compensation, as I do use a server method with no client stub to insert. The server method does verification, makes sure I'm not blocked from posting, adds timestamps, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of question comes up regularly. The fix that works in most cases, and probably also in yours, is to make sure that the same constraints are used on the client as on the server (or, if anything, that the constraints on the client are more restrictive). I'm assuming that you are doing the `Posts.find` on the server? If so, then make sure to add the same conditions to the `find` in the template helper on the client.

Comment: I'm not sure that's easily done. My use case here is comments, so from the server I publish all of the relevant comments but on the client I limit those that I render. I have a 'view all comments' button that removes the limit (and therefore the problem) but the idea here is to keep the limit

Comment: The serverside find() function that is published is identical to the client ohe except there is no limit from the server.